# Using a variable ColumnName

Tags: c#, linq, variables

I wrote this:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
                from user in ObjDT_usuario.AsEnumerable()
                where user.Field<string>("Name").StartsWith(query,true,null)
                select user;
```

It Works fine.

I want to use a variable:

```
string ColumnName1 = "Name";
IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
                from user in ObjDT_usuario.AsEnumerable()
                where user.Field<string>(ColumnName1).StartsWith(query,true,null)
                select user;
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this work? What's the problem\error\issue\concern?

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem was a unassigned local variable. Sorry! The above code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're using `query` twice:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> **query** =
                from user in ObjDT_usuario.AsEnumerable()
                where user.Field<string>(ColumnName1).StartsWith(**query**,true,null)
                select user;
```

If you choose a different variable name you should be fine:

```
string columnName = "Name";
IEnumerable<DataRow> users =
                from user in ObjDT_usuario.AsEnumerable()
                where user.Field<string>(columnName).StartsWith(query,true,null)
                select user;
```